# Complex analysis book recommendation (for beginners)

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book to get started with complex analysis, my experience with analysis has been purely real analysis, up to the Riemann-Stieltjes integral (clearly having studied topics such as bounded variation, series of functions, etc.), I have been suggested the book "COMPLEX ANALYSIS An Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable" by Lars V. Ahlfors. Is this a good document to get me started? Any other suggestions? thanks!

Comment: You might also want to look at Complex Variables and Applications by Churchill and Brown.

Comment: Churchill does not assume much knowledge of real analysis. It’s a bit more of an applications book. Try Gamelin. It’s more modern than Ahlfors and, I think, a good book.

Comment: I personally purchased [An Introduction To Complex Function Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Complex-Function-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/038797427X/ref=sr_1_1?crid=32S212C5QAC60&keywords=bruce+palka+complex+analysis&qid=1702351189&sprefix=bruce+palka+complex+analysis%2Caps%2C118&sr=8-1) by Bruce Palka.  I suggest that you examine the corresponding Amazon reviews.  The downside is that it is a bit pricey.